# Why __flush_dcache_area undefined？

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I'm using xzynqmp cpu(armv8), I want to flush cache and use "__flush_dcache_area" api.

But, compile result is:

"WARNING: "__flush_dcache_area" xxxx undefined!"

Does any one know why?

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in your code.

`#include <asm/cacheflush.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The symbol doesn't have the scope beyond kernel, to use it, you can export it in the kernel source file with EXPORT_SYMBOL();